# Bun Build giving me index.html with blank pages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, bun

So I was trying to create a webpage and wanted to do that in bun. Here is the structure of my webpage:

[image: tree structure]

The issue that I'm facing right now is that, if I try to start the webpage using `bun start` then the webpage works flawlessly, I'm able to navigate between multiple pages (since I'm using `react-router-dom`), however, when I perform a `bun build`, then the `index.html` that I get isn't correct. The landing page itself is correct, however, when I try to access the other pages, it just shows me a blank screen. I'm not fully sure about why that might be.

Here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "land",
  "version": "0.1.61",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
    "cjs": "^0.0.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.8",
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "bun dev",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build2": "tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./src/output.css",
    "watch": "tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./src/output.css --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-refresh": "0.10.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "latest"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "homepage": "."
}
```

Here is my App.tsx

```
// import "./App.css";
import './output.css'
import React from 'react';
import Events from './Websites Store/Events.tsx';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './Websites Store/MainPage.tsx';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" role="main">
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Main />} />
        <Route path='events' element={<Events />} />
      </Routes>

      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com" />
        <link href="/src/output.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
      </head>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have the watch statement since I was using tailwind CSS.

I can provide any more information if it is needed.

Furthermore, I was also curious about would it be possible to switch from bun to npm mid project? I'm not quite sure about the specifics of either and was curious about being able to switch between them?

Comment: After you build the app using `bun build` how are you then running/serving the built artifact?

Comment: I run the app with `serve -s build`. I also tried it by just opening index.html within the build folder

Comment: I've never heard of `bun`. Are you using any special/custom webpack config or anything like that?

Comment: https://bun.sh/ Here is where I used bun from

Comment: You could try the command "bun x serve build/"